# Android App Crashing Upon Launch

Tags: java, android

So I'm having to work on an App to play the game Craps, and I had to modify it to allow for a home screen with rules, a buy in system, and a betting system. Up until this modification the app worked with no issues at all, but after adding in the modifications, the app crashes the instant I launch it. At this point, I can't find anything that fixes it, and the answers listed on other threads seem to be non-applicable, so I'm turning to SO for help. Below is all of my code:
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".CrapsGame">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Craps!</string>
<string name="Banner_Text">Try your luck!</string>
<string name="roll_Total">2</string>
<string name="players_Wincount">Your wins: 0</string>
<string name="house_Wincount">House wins: 0</string>
<string name="button_Name">Roll!</string>
<string name="player_Wins">You won!</string>
<string name="Point">Point: </string>
<string name="house_Wins">Better luck next time!</string>
<string name="rulesminBuy">Minimum buy-in is $5.00, no change!</string>
<string name="rulesmaxBuy">Maximum buy-in is $200.00, no change!</string>
<string name="rulesminBet">Minimum bet is $1.00</string>
<string name="rulesmaxBet">Maximum bet is $50.00</string>
<string name="rulesgameRules">Roll a 7 or 11 on your first roll and you win twice your bet!</string>
<string name="rulesgameRulesTwo">Roll a 2, 3, or 12 and you lose twice your bet!</string>
<string name="rulesgameRulesThree">Roll anything else and that becomes your point!</string>
<string name="rulesgameRulesFour">Roll your point again to win, but if you roll a 7 you lose!</string>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/die1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/die1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rollTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/roll_Total" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/die2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/die1" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pointbox"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Point" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/playerWins"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/players_Wincount" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/houseWins"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/house_Wincount" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/OrderButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_Name"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bannerTwo"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="50px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Banner_Text"
    android:layout_weight="0.15" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAmmount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="$5.00 minimum"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buyInButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:text="Buy In!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesgameRules" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesgameRulesTwo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesgameRulesThree" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesgameRulesFour" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesminBuy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesmaxBuy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesminBet" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rulesmaxBet" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
package com.example.kasresredux.akeelin3_groupassignment01;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class CrapsGame extends AppCompatActivity {

//Developer note: as it was not specifically asked for, nor do I expect people to understand how to do it in an introduction
//class, I didn't include any way for the computer to save the information on screen rotation, so the app does kill and restart.

//Create the random function as well as the required variables. They're outside of a method so they can be used anywhere.
Random randomRoll = new Random();
int dieRollOne, dieRollTwo = 1;
int tempRoll;
int rollTotal = 2;
boolean isFirstDie, firstRoll = true;
int playerWins = 0;
int houseWins = 0;
int pointValue = 0;
int buyInAmmount = 0;
int betAmount = 1;
int currentTotalValue;

//onCreate method used to handle layout control and to handle the rolls in a separate method.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    final Button buyInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyInButton);
    //Check that the buy-in is legal and, if it is, proceed to the game.
    buyInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
          final EditText buyInCounter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAmmount);
          try {
              buyInAmmount = Integer.parseInt(buyInCounter.toString());
          }
          catch (NumberFormatException e){

          }
          if (buyInAmmount >= 5.00)
          {
              currentTotalValue = buyInAmmount;
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome, and good luck!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_craps_game);
          }
          else if (buyInCounter == null)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your buy-in amount!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else if (buyInAmmount <= 4.99)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter at least a five dollar minimum buy in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else if (buyInAmmount > 500)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The maximum buy-in is $500!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
    });

    //This may be unneeded, but I wanted to be certain.
    if (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels < getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels) {
        final Button buttonRoll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OrderButton);
        buttonRoll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                rollHandler();
            }
        });
    }
    else if (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels > getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels) {
        final Button buttonRoll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OrderButton);
        buttonRoll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                rollHandler();
            }
        });
    }
    final Button increaseBetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increaseBet);
    final Button descreaseBetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lowerBet);
    increaseBetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            increaseBet();
        }
    });
    descreaseBetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            decreaseBet();
        }
    });
}

//Main code for deciding the rolls.
public void rollResults() {
    //Reset rollTotal so it can't go infinitely large.
    rollTotal = 0;
    //Decide that this is for the first of two dice images.
    isFirstDie = true;
    tempRoll = randomRoll.nextInt(6);
    dieRollOne = decideImage(tempRoll, isFirstDie);
    //Add the dieRoll result RATHER than tempRoll as tempRoll will be one lower than we need, and we aren't rolling 1d6-1.
    rollTotal += dieRollOne;
    isFirstDie = false;
    tempRoll = randomRoll.nextInt(6);
    dieRollTwo = decideImage(tempRoll, isFirstDie);
    rollTotal += dieRollTwo;
}
//Method used to change the image of the die.
public int decideImage(int roll, boolean dieRollOne) {
    //Find the die to change, and set that image to what it should be. Sadly, no fancy roll animations will be included.
    ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die1);
    ImageView u = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die2);
    if (dieRollOne == true) {
        switch (roll) {
            case 0:
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
                return 1;
            case 1:
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
                return 2;
            case 2:
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
                return 3;
            case 3:
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
                return 4;
            case 4:
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
                return 5;
            case 5:
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
                return 6;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    } else if (dieRollOne == false) {
        switch (roll) {
            case 0:
                u.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
                return 1;
            case 1:
                u.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
                return 2;
            case 2:
                u.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
                return 3;
            case 3:
                u.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
                return 4;
            case 4:
                u.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
                return 5;
            case 5:
                u.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
                return 6;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//The real logic of the game.
public void rollHandler() {
    //Find the required textboxes. As they have the same ID in landscape and portrait, we can do it all in one go.
    final TextView playerWinCountBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerWins);
    final TextView houseWinCountBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.houseWins);
    final TextView pointCountBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointbox);
    final TextView rollTotalBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollTotal);
    final TextView currentTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BankTotal);
    //Call the roll method.
    rollResults();
    //Set the roll Total
    rollTotalBox.setText("" + rollTotal);
    //If this is the first time we're rolling, check if the player gets craps or wins, or if the game continues.
    if (firstRoll == true) {
        pointCountBox.setText("Point: ");
        if (rollTotal == 7 || rollTotal == 11) {
            playerWins++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You won!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            playerWinCountBox.setText("Player Wins: " + playerWins);
            currentTotalValue += betAmount*2;
            currentTotal.setText("Current Total: $"+currentTotalValue+".00");
        } else if (rollTotal == 2 || rollTotal == 3 || rollTotal == 12) {
            houseWins++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Better luck next time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            houseWinCountBox.setText("House Wins: " + houseWins);
            currentTotalValue -= betAmount * 2;
            currentTotal.setText("Current Total: $"+currentTotalValue+".00");
            if (currentTotalValue < betAmount)
            {
                decreaseBet(currentTotalValue);
            }
        } else {
            pointValue = rollTotal;
            firstRoll = false;
            pointCountBox.setText("Point: " + pointValue);
        }
    }
    //As the game continued, check if they get the 7, or if they win. If neither, the program just ends the method as it runs out of code.
    else if (firstRoll == false) {
        if (rollTotal == 7) {
            houseWins++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Better luck next time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            houseWinCountBox.setText("House Wins: " + houseWins);
            currentTotalValue -= betAmount;
            currentTotal.setText("Current Total: $"+currentTotalValue+".00");
            if (currentTotalValue < betAmount)
            {
                decreaseBet(currentTotalValue);
            }
            firstRoll = true;
        } else if (rollTotal == pointValue) {
            playerWins++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You won!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            playerWinCountBox.setText("Player Wins: " + playerWins);
            firstRoll = true;
            currentTotalValue += betAmount;
            currentTotal.setText("Current Total: $"+currentTotalValue+".00");
        }
    }
}
public void increaseBet() {
    final TextView currentBet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.betView);
    if (betAmount + 1 <= currentTotalValue)
    {
        betAmount++;
        currentBet.setText("$"+betAmount+".00");
    }
    else if (betAmount + 1 > currentTotalValue)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can't bet more than you have!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (betAmount + 1 > 50)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The maximum bet is $50", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void decreaseBet(){
    final TextView currentBet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.betView);
    if (betAmount - 1 >= 1)
    {
        betAmount--;
        currentBet.setText("$"+betAmount+".00");
    }
    else if (betAmount - 1 <= 1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The minimum bet is $1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
//Specific version of decreaseBet that will be used when the user loses so much that their current bet no longer is legal.
public void decreaseBet(int newBet){
    final TextView currentBet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.betView);
    betAmount = newBet;
    currentBet.setText("$"+betAmount+".00");
    if (betAmount < 1)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm afraid you can no longer meet the minimum bet! Better luck next time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

---

I apologize, I know it's a lot of code to pour over, but if someone can find the fix, I'd appreciate it greatly~!

Comment: You should share logcat to check why and in which line your apps crashes.

Comment: Yap, try to retrieve the error in logcat when your app crashes, and share it with us. Otherwise, it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: I can't emulate my program on the computer, and I can't seem to find how to get the logs on my Android device, seeing as to test I have to build an APK and send it via email.

Comment: Just install Apk In Your Device And Connect Your Phone With m/c where you Create Project In Android Studio. It will Give You Logcat signed Apk Also

Comment: Okay, I managed to get my emulator somewhat functioning, and what I seemed to get was "Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.kasresredux.akeelin3_groupassignment01/com.example.kasresredux.akeelin3_groupassignment01.CrapsGame" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity" I have no clue what this means